# Python - remove duplicates from list with different suffixes

Tags: python, list, sorting, set

I have:

```
['asdf/ws', 'abc/abc/', 'asdf/wss', 'asdf/', 'ab/wss', 'ab/ws', 'abc/abc/ws', 'xyz/wss']
```

I need:

```
['asdf/ws', 'abc/abc/', 'ab/wss', 'xyz/wss']
```

Where possible suffixes are:

```
/
/ws
/wss
```

- the prefix can be any string
- the prefix will contain unspecified number of additional forward slashes
- the first unique prefixed item in the list from the left would be selected.

The application is pinging websockets and returning a list of connections with lowest latency without knowing which suffix is correct for each socket.  Some sockets allow multiple suffixes, some allow only one type.  Sometimes the admin of the socket changes the required suffix without notice.  Once each socket returns ping, the list is sorted by latency, but then I have duplicates that need to be removed.

typically, to remove duplicates in a list I would do:

```
list(set(my_List))
```

but that doesn't work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = ['asdf/ws', 'abc/abc/', 'asdf/wss', 'asdf/', 'ab/wss', 'ab/ws', 'abc/abc/ws', 'xyz/wss']

# use a set to cache duplicates
caches = set()
results = []

for item in lst:

    prefix = item.rsplit('/', 2)[0]

    # check whether prefix already exists
    if prefix not in caches:

        results.append(item)
        caches.add(prefix)

results
# ['asdf/ws', 'abc/abc/', 'ab/wss', 'xyz/wss']
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as best because it is most readable solution presented and this is public financial software for lay users; readability is important.  However I think item.rsplit('/', 2)[0] is error; I'm using item.rsplit('/', 1)[0]

Answer (score 2):

First we extract only the elements with the desired suffixes (end neglect duplicates , note that this might change the order!)

```
proc1= list(set([x for x in test if x.endswith('/') or x.endswith('/ws') or x.endswith('/wss')]))
```

In the next step we use two lists. One for storing the already included prefixes and the other for storing the desired elements. If a prefix is already used, don't include the element with this prefix and check the next one.

```
proc_f = []
proc_suff = []
for x in proc1:
    if x.split("/")[0] not in proc_suff:
        proc_suff.append(x.split("/")[0])
        proc_f.append(x)

prof_f
['ab/ws', 'asdf/wss', 'abc/abc/ws', 'xyz/wss']
```

Comment: Very nice answer! +1

Comment: this did not return the correct result; for example should have been ab/wss; sometimes one of the two has significantly different latency because it redirects to the other.

Comment: well, because I converted to set() the order of the elements changed. If that is crucial I'm going to change it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to check if any of the prefixes have already been spotted i.e a connection with the same prefix exists behind it in the returned pinged responses:

```
import re
s = ['asdf/ws', 'abc/abc/', 'asdf/wss', 'asdf/', 'ab/wss', 'ab/ws', 'abc/abc/ws', 'xyz/wss']
new_s = [a for i, a in enumerate(s) if not any(re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', a)[0] == re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', c)[0] for c in s[:i])]
```

Output:

```
['asdf/ws', 'abc/abc/', 'ab/wss', 'xyz/wss']
```

Comment: using regex for this task is pretty elegant and exactly the way to go. This should be the correct answer to the question.

Comment: @pythonic833 Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try dict approach:

```
data=['asdf/ws', 'abc/abc/', 'asdf/wss', 'asdf/', 'ab/wss', 'ab/ws', 'abc/abc/ws', 'xyz/wss']

unique_items={}
for i in data:
    data_suffic=i.split('/')
    if data_suffic[0] not in unique_items:
        unique_items[data_suffic[0]]="/".join(data_suffic)

print(unique_items.values())

['abc/abc/', 'asdf/ws', 'ab/wss', 'xyz/wss']
```

updated for keeping the order :

```
data=['asdf/ws', 'abc/abc/', 'asdf/wss', 'asdf/', 'ab/wss', 'ab/ws', 'abc/abc/ws', 'xyz/wss']

unique_items={}
for j,i in enumerate(data):
    data_suffic=i.split('/')
    if data_suffic[0] not in unique_items:
        unique_items[data_suffic[0]]=(j,"/".join(data_suffic))

print(list(map(lambda x:x[1],sorted(unique_items.values(),key=lambda x:x[0]))))
```

output:

```
['asdf/ws', 'abc/abc/', 'ab/wss', 'xyz/wss']
```

Comment: unfortunately this loses the latency sorted order of the list

Comment: @litepresence now its returning in the correct order.